# How does native English speakers pronounce "that he"?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm watching this Youtube video at https://youtu.be/BTMj0jlu5r8?t=190. At around 3:10, the narrator said:

> ... in fact that he slammed ...

He said it too fast and I can't hear how exactly he pronounce *that he*. Could anyone help to explain what exactly he pronounced? I want to learn it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I heard “that he” clearly - fast I grant you, but both words are there - in an American accent though....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what I hear is something like [ðəɾi]. The /h/ at the start of "he" may be elided when the word is unstressed. This causes the /t/ at the end of "that" to be between two vowels, so it becomes the voiced "flap/tap" sound [ɾ].

In British English, it's less common to "flap/tap" the /t/ sound. Instead, it may be turned into a "glottal stop" [ʔ] in a context like this.